# Prove a bilinear operator is symmetric and positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I'm having problem showing the following:

All operators are defined on $V$ which is real (not complex).
Let $f$ be a bilinear operator that is anti-symetric (meaning $f(a,b)=-f(b,a))$ and let $J$ be a linear operator s.t $J^2=-I$.
Also, I know that rank$(f)=\dim V=n$.
I need to prove that if for every $a,b$ in $V$ we define $S$ bilinear operator s.t:
$$
S(a,b) = f(a,J(b))
$$
then $S$ is symmetric $(S(a,b)=S(b,a))$ and positive definite $(S(v,v)\geq v$ for all $v$ in $V$).

My thoughts are:
Immediately notice that $a^tSb=afJb \iff S=fJ$

However I don't know what to do from here.

(I gave some examples for myself for possible J's and it seems to be anti-symetric but I don't know how to prove it).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your definition of "positive definite" is wrong. But with either defnition of "positive definite", the statement about positive-definiteness of $S$ is wrong, because you could always replace $f$ by $-f$ (or alternatively $J$ by $-J$) and all the signs would switch. Finally, you should have written that $f$ is supposed to have target $\mathbb R$ (not $V$ or something else), or equivalently called it a "bilinear form" instead of a "bilinear operator". I'm not sure about the statement about the symmetry of $S$; this might also be missing a condition (that $f$ be $J$-invariant?).

Answer (score 1):

None of this is true.

As [darij grinberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/586/darij-grinberg) already explained in the comments, $S$ is not necessarily positive definite. A simple example would be $f(a,b) = a^T J b$ for antisymmetric $J$ such that $J^2 = -{\rm I}$, for example, $J = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} & 1 \\ -1 \end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

As for symmetricity (order must be even if we want to have a real $J$ such that $J^2 = {\rm I}$), I'm quite sure that the statement is true for the matrices of order $2$. However, for order $4$, it is not too hard to construct a counterexample:

\begin{align*}
F &:= Y - Y^T = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -3 & -6 & -9 \\ 3 & 0 & -3 & -6 \\ 6 & 3 & 0 & -3 \\ 9 & 6 & 3 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad Y := \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \end{bmatrix}, \\
J &:= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

It is easy to see that $f(a,b) = a^T F b$ defines an antisymmetric bilinear form and that $J^2 = -{\rm I}$.

But,

$$S(e_1, e_4) = -3 \ne 15 = S(e_4, e_1),$$

where $e_1$ and $e_4$ denote the first and the fourth vectors of the [canonical basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis) of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

On a side note, $J$ need not be antisymmetric. Check my example (as a whole, and/or each of the diagonal blocks in $J$).